# Spanish characters in email appearing as question mark in mail clients

Tags: php, email, email-client

I am using an already written Mail class in php. Emails are mostly sent in spanish language. Following are the headers being passed to the php mail function -

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
```

Also additional headers are being appended to the message (don't know what it does),

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
```

Emails appear properly in browsers but in mail clients, accented characters are replaced by question marks

for eg:

```
Una nueva contraseña se solicito
```

appears

```
Una nueva contrase�a se solicito
```

have checked this in Thunderbird and outlook

How do I fix this to show these characters correctly in mail clients as well

Comment: why there is only one apostrophe in this row : `Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8`

Comment: sorry that was a typo.. edited the question now

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have to change the character set to UTF-8 in Thunderbird and Outlook as well.

Answer (score 1):

The email is probably being sent out as something other than UTF-8. Make sure to convert the text to UTF-8 before passing it to the class (or convert it to UTF-8 in the class).

Answer (score 0):

Like Raffael say the client have to be in UTF-8 too, the better solution is to pass with htmlentities before sending the mail and display the mail as HTML

Comment: yes i tried that but didn't help.. strangely the problem was solved by replacing 'UTF-8' with 'ISO-8859-1'. I guess the clients have this character set selected by default. Works for now but not sure if it would cause any trouble in case of other languages.